# Why was quartz not a major product of the Lunar Magma Ocean?

Tags: planetary-science, petrology, mantle, moon

Fractional crystallisation generally makes magma more silicic. Why was a substantial quartz layer not a product of the stratification of the Lunar mantle?

Comment: can you please add a bit more context to your question and maybe a link or two so i can learn more about the minerals found on the moon.

Comment: Quartz is almost pure silica (100% SiO2). Magmas have a silica content ranging between, say, ~45 wt% (basalt) up to ~75 wt% (rhyolite). Moreover, making silicic magmas implies fractional crystallisation of *mafic* minerals: it is by removing those minerals from the melt that you can make the melt more silicic. So you'll never crystallize 100% SiO2 minerals while making >75 wt% SiO2 magmas.

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival: if that comment was an answer I'd up vote it.

Comment: @Fred Ok, I'll try to expand on this later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fractional crystallization indeed makes magmas more silicic. However, you'll never reach a magma composition with 100 % silica, which could then cool and crystallize as quartz. The starting material (i.e., mantle rocks like peridotite) is just too mafic. For this part, see answers to [Why aren't there ultra acid igneous rocks?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/20117/18081)

If you are thinking of the crystals left over by the fractional crystallization process, generally referred to as "extract", "cumulate", or "residue", they are always *less* silicic than the starting material. It has to be, if you want to make the magma more silicic while keeping the mass-balance. The process can be graphically represented like this (redrawn after [Cox et al., 1979](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-017-3373-1)):

[image]

The three diagrams represent the fractional crystallization process of a parental magma (PM), yielding a diffentiated magma (DM), more silicic, and a less silicic residue (R) consisting of one (top) to three (bottom) minerals. The mass balance, for an element $\alpha$, can then be written as:

$C_0^{\alpha} = FC_L^{\alpha} + (1 - F)\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n (m_i c_i^{\alpha})$

where $C_0^{\alpha}$ is the concentration of said element in the parental magma, $C_L^{\alpha}$ the concentration of the element in the differentiated magma, $F$ the fraction of liquid remaining, $m_i$ is the mass fraction of each of the $n$ minerals in the cumulate, and $c_i^{\alpha}$ is the concentration of element $\alpha$ in mineral $i$. You see that even if somehow the diffentiated magma had a 100 wt% SiO2 composition, the crystals left in the residue would be less silicic, hence not quartz.